# OnTeamsTaskModuleFetchAsync signature change between 4.6 and 4.7.2

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

Bot builder 4.6 had 
protected virtual Task OnTeamsTaskModuleFetchAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, TaskModuleRequest taskModuleRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken);

but bot builder 4.7.2 doesn't have this. Any specific reason?
We want to return a task module iframe when someone clicks view details button on adaptive card. How can we do that using 4.7.2?

Comment: Could you please try out the latest sample for [TaskModule](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/54.teams-task-module)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer

```
new TaskModuleResponse
{
    Task = new TaskModuleContinueResponse
    {
        Value = new TaskModuleTaskInfo()
        {
            Height = TaskModuleHeight,
            Width = TaskModuleWidth,
            Title = PageTitle,
            Url = PageURI,
        },
    },
};
```